# Interface documentation not acessible from interface implementation class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Can I somehow instruct visual studio to automatically copy any interface member XML documentation to its implementation class?

According to this [MSDN How-To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04awywx.aspx) updated for this exact effect just 2 months ago, one is supposed to. But I can't replicate this behavior in any way. Also looking at the xml file in that article, there's in fact no entry for the interface implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, VS itself cannot do this. Our [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) automatically inherits comments from base and implemented types when it generates documentation. Moreover, it can explicitly add the inherited comment into source code.

Comment: Yes. I suspect that isn't possible too. Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I'm well aware of them. My interest was solely if this feature had been integrated into Visual Studio without me knowing, after I stumbled upon that How-To article.

Answer (score 2):

I use [submain GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) - it's a free visual studio plugin which automatically documents code blocks, either by copying from base class / interface documentation, or intelligently trying to guess the documentation (which is surprisingly effective). I couldn't develop without it these days.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/)
it has `<inheritdoc/>` which allows you to inherit documentation from base types.